# Error "Class 'Swift_EmbeddedFile' not found" when i try send email with yii2 advanced

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I tried build application with auto send mail.

Before I build in yii2 advanced, I tried in yii2 basic and my code work.
But when i tried in yii2 advanced, I got error

> Class 'Swift_EmbeddedFile' not found

Can somebody help me?

And this is my code :

code in /common/config/main-local.php

```
return [
'components' => [
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
               'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
               'host' => 'mysmtp',
               'username' => 'myusername',
               'password' => 'mypassword',
               'port' => 'myport',
         ],
    ],
],];
```

And my code in MyController :

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('layouts/index.php', [
                        'imageFileName' => Yii::getAlias('@app/mail/layouts/images/logo.png'),
                        'facebook' => Yii::getAlias('@app/mail/layouts/images/facebook.png'),
                        'twitter' => Yii::getAlias('@app/mail/layouts/images/twitter.png'),
                        'pinterest' => Yii::getAlias('@app/mail/layouts/images/pinterest.png')
                        ]) // a view rendering result becomes the message body here
                    ->setFrom('from@email.com')
                    ->setTo($model->email)
                    ->setSubject('Message Test 3')
                    ->send();
```

Note : I have Swiftmailer extention.

Thanks in advance for your help guys.

Comment: Have you tried to run `composer update` again on this advanced template project?

Comment: [SOLVED] after i run composer update.

Now no error but my email is empty.
My html view not include in email.
can you help me @Bizley ??

Comment: Check if path to `layouts/index.php` can be found. Also remember that `@app` alias is automatically pointing to the current running application in advanced template so maybe you need to specify it like `@console` or `@backend`.